Construir un objeto de entidad a partir de un DTO (Java)
Estoy haciendo una aplicación siguiendo el patrón MVC y necesito saber como hacer para construir un objeto de tipo Entidad a partir de datos primitivos que vienen en un DTO. Me corrigieron que no debería existir relación entre ambos objetos, Vino y VinoDto. Traté de corregirlo de esta forma pero ¿cómo podría hacerlo más elegante?
Tengo este método de un objeto de Control que se encarga de invocar el constructor de Vino
public Vino crearVino(int aniada, String imagenEtiqueta, String nombre, String notaCata, double precio,
                      String varietalNombre) {

    if (varietal == null) {  //constructor con creacion de varietal
        return new Vino(aniada, bodegaSeleccionada, imagenEtiqueta, nombre, notaCata, precio,
                varietalNombre, tipoUva, maridaje);
    } else {//constructor sin creacion de varietal
        return new Vino(aniada, bodegaSeleccionada, imagenEtiqueta, nombre, notaCata,
                precio, varietal, maridaje);
    }
}

y este es el método que se encarga de buscar los datos para el constructor
public void actualizarDatosDeVino() {
    int index = 0;
    for (VinoDto vinoDto : vinosImportados) {

        int aniada = vinoDto.getAniada();
        String imagenEtiqueta = vinoDto.getImagenEtiqueta();
        String nombre = vinoDto.getNombre();
        String nombreBodega = bodegaSeleccionada.getNombre();
        double precio = vinoDto.getPrecioARS();
        String notaCata = vinoDto.getNotaDeCataBodega();
        String varietalNombre = vinoDto.getVarietal();

        if (bodegaSeleccionada.actualizarDatosDeVino(vinosSist.get(index),aniada,nombreBodega,
                precio,imagenEtiqueta,notaCata)) {

            index++;
        } else {//setea atributos del gestor
            buscarVarietal(vinoDto.getVarietal());
            buscarTipoUva(vinoDto.getTipoDeUva());
            buscarMaridaje(vinoDto.getMaridaje());

            Vino nuevo = crearVino(aniada,imagenEtiqueta,nombre, notaCata, precio, varietalNombre);
            vinosSist.add(nuevo);
        }
    }
}


"Me corrigieron que no deberia existir relacion entre ambos objetos(Vino y VinoDto), trate de corregirlo de esta forma" -> Pues pregúntale a quién te corrigió... yo veo que Vino y VinoDto tienen una relación obvia pues ambos representan el mismo objeto (uno internamente y otro externamente, pero son las "dos caras" del mismo modelo). Imagino que lo suyo sería tener un método en alguna clase de utilidades que te permita pasar un tipo al otro. Todo depende de qué librerías tengas, yo prefiero hacer estas cosas con mapstruct, pero un simple método en una clase también hace lo mismo.

existe una dependencia mapstruct. con ella se hacen mapeos. en la interfac que creas pude psar de DTO a entidad y de entidad a DTO y lo hace el por detras automaticamente. echale un vistazo
https://github.com/carlos033/PruebaInditex/blob/main/src/main/java/com/inditex/aplicacion/mapper/MapperPrice.java

Coincido completamente con Benito-B. La relación lógica entre ambos existe, tal y como él ha descrito. Lo que te han indicado básicamente es que el mapeo entre una y otra no debería estar incluido dentro de ninguna de las dos. Puedes implementar ese mapeo en el Controlador, en el Servicio o en una clase aparte para mapeos que se llame desde una de esas dos. En todos estos casos puedes emplear librerías auxiliares como MapStruct  o Apache Commons.

Gracias por la ayuda voy a usar esa sugerencia

@Benito-B no fui claro del todo. Lo que me corrigio es que yo estaba llamando los getters de DTO en el contructor de la entidad, algo asi:
Vino nuevo = new Vino(vinoDto.getAniada,vinoDto.getImagenEtiqueta, vinoDto.getNombre...etc)
entonces por eso descompuse en variables cada uno de los atributos del DTO,antes de llamarse el metodo constructor para crear el objeto de entidad
